# python pandas function calculated row by row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I have a data frame with the following structure:

"data"

```
        Demand x(t)
week             
1                  18
2                  29
3                  25
4                  35
5                  40
6                  45
7                  49
8                  42
9                  31
10                 30
11                 25
12                 22
```

I plan to estimate the forecast for the next periods using Holt's method with exponential smoothing. For that, I will use two new columns: level and trend, knowing the data for the first row (week 1):

```
                    demand  level  trend
week                      
1             18   18.0    7.0
2             29    NaN    NaN
3             25    NaN    NaN
4             35    NaN    NaN
5             40    NaN    NaN
6             45    NaN    NaN
7             49    NaN    NaN
8             42    NaN    NaN
9             31    NaN    NaN
10            30    NaN    NaN
11            25    NaN    NaN
12            22    NaN    NaN
```

To complete the forecast, I need to estimate the level and the trend for each week, which uses the previous week as basis. I was able to do it by using a for loop:

```
for idx in range(2,13):
        new_level = alpha*data.loc[idx].demand + (1-alpha)*(data.loc[idx-1].level + data.loc[idx-1].trend)
        new_trend = beta*(new_level -data.loc[idx-1].level) + (1-beta)*(data.loc[idx-1].trend)
        data.loc[idx] = (data.loc[idx].demand, new_level, new_trend)
```

and the result

```
        demand      level     trend
week                             
1           18.0  18.000000  7.000000
2           29.0  27.000000  7.660000
3           25.0  29.830000  6.066100
4           35.0  35.448050  5.918243
5           40.0  40.683147  5.692805
6           45.0  45.687976  5.465773
7           49.0  50.076874  5.110404
8           42.0  48.593639  2.934503
9           31.0  41.264071 -0.452640
10          30.0  35.405716 -2.236526
11          25.0  29.084595 -3.584443
12          22.0  23.750076 -4.161968
```

I am wondering if there is a better way. I tried with using shift, but my problem is that both the level and the trend depend on current data and previous data calculated "on the fly", so I will need somehow a simultaneous cal of the two columns to use:

```
data['level'] = alpha*data.demand + (1-alpha)*(data.level.shift(1)+data.trend.shift(1))
data['trend'] = beta*(data.level-data.level.shift(1)) + (1-beta)*data.trend.shift(1)
```

any suggestion?

Comment: what is `alpha` and `beta`

Comment: What doesn't work with last two lines?

Comment: alpha and beta are just constants. The last two lines didn't work because they need to be simultaneous, otherwise, you don't have previous row level/trend for the calcs.